# How to set a search box to only search through a specific library?

Tags: search, search-results, scope, scopedisplaygroup

I have done lots of reading on this site as well as others, and tried lots of different options. What I am trying to do is create a "search page" for a database, and both of these pages (search page & database page) are both libraries (search page was made a library even though no documents will be here because I couldn't get a web-parts page to appear in the quick launch). I have a few documents in the database page, no problems there. In the search page I have a search box & search core results box. I have tried to create a scope by using the database library URL + /SiteAssets as a rule (requiring).  When I change this it takes like 15 minutes until the update is made in the scope, but then in my "view scopes" page the scope that's been created is not "shared" nor does it have any items (says not available). I have also modified the "search dropdown" display group to only show this new scope, but when I go to mess around with the scope settings on the search box it doesn't show up! What do I need to do? Maybe there is another approach? I am using SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the response Supermode! So I finally got it to work! Not sure what did it, I changed the "Scope" in the locations settings for the search core results web part to the name of the new scope (I had URL of the library I wanted to be scoped previously). And the issue with none of the items being "available" in the "Search Scopes" menu disappeared after I changed the rule to "include" instead of "require". Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create search scope to target specific library. Here is a video tutorial in how to do it.
http://www.bentedder.com/create-a-search-scope-for-a-sharepoint-2010-list-or-library/

Hope any helps